# Using Javascript with Rails to display alert dialogs using Bootbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, bootbox

I'm new to Rails and have been trying to display a success message when signing successfully to a website. I've been trying to use bootbox.js to display messages that are stored within a ruby hash once sign in is successful - unfortunately I am even newer to Javascript and when I create a successful sign in I can't get any of the bootbox content to display. The code below shows where I want to display the message.

```
<div class="sidebar pull-left">
  <!-- sidebar -->
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="list-group">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <%= link_to '', root_path, class: "fa fa-home fa-fw fa-stack-1x" %>
      </span>
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <%= link_to '', help_path, class: "fa fa-question fa-fw fa-stack-1x" %>
      </span>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "flash_messages", data: {flash: flash} do %>
  <% end %>

  <% content_for :alert do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      <%= render 'users/show_flash_messages.js' %>
    </script>
  <% end %>

  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= yield :alert %>
  <% end %>  
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

I use 
      <%= content_tag :div, class: "flash_messages", data: {flash: flash} do %>
      <% end %>
to pass the data inside the hash to a javascript array on the client.
The ruby hash is initialised in the controller here:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # sign_in @user 
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I then created a method in users.js.coffee which I hoped would display the alert using the bootbox alert dialog by taking the required information from the js array:

```
Messages = flashMessage: (flash) ->
flash_message = flash[1]
bootbox.alert flash_message
return
```

I wrote this in javascript and then used a converter to convert it to coffeescript (should this work?). I then have a rails javascript file named _show_flash_messages.js.erb where I call into the flashMessage function.

```
$(function() {
    messages = $('.flash_messages').data('flash');
    Messages.flashMessage(messages);
});
```

I've been able to display the information in a bootstrap alert however my preference is to use these bootbox dialogs to display the information. Like I said I'm new to Rails and this is my first attempt at properly integrating javascript so it is likely that I am missing something obvious.

For reference this is the HTML for the page that the dialog will hopefully be displayed on top of:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="center hero-unit">
    <div class="user-profile">
      <span class="user-header">
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <h2>
            <%= @user.name %>
        </h2>
      </span>
      <span id="page-content">
        <p>
            This is where a short biography will go.
        </p>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```